# How can I display Html5/javascript contents in wxwidgets

Tags: javascript, c++, html

I would like to write a C++ project with wxwidgets and google's v8 engine.
but i have no idea how can i display it on widgets
is there any example code?

Comment: I googled for *webkit wxwidgets* and got [this](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_web_view.html)

Comment: I cannot build with this.. too terrible to solve this. I decide to use QT then